# django NoReverseMatch with multiple pk values

Tags: django, django-templates, foreign-keys, primary-key, django-urls

I've built a test case to demonstrate a problem with django urls and class based view when accessing multiple pk values.

The file which demonstrates the problem is `addressbook/family/templates/family/family_detail.html` and I've commented out the lines of my attempts.

I would like to link to a specific person from a family detail page, but the first commented attempt gives `NoReverseMatch  at /family/2/  . Reverse for 'person-detail' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['family/(?P<pk>\\d+)/person/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']`

The second and their third commented attempts spin on the server for a long time, and then eventually give `error at /family/1/patient/1/
redefinition of group name 'pk' as group 2; was group 1`

Project structure is:

```
addressbook/
           addressbook/
                      urls.py
           family/
                 models.py
                 urls.py
                 views.py
                 templates/family/
                                  family_detail.html
                                  family_form.html
                                  family_list.html
           person/
                  models.py
                  urls.py
                  views.py
                  templates/person/
                                   person_detail.html
                                   person_form.html
```

`addressbook/addressbook/urls.py`

```py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^family/',include('family.urls',namespace='family')),
)
```

`addresbook/family/models.py`

```py
from django.db import models

class Family(models.Model):
    lastname=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastname
```

`addressbook/family/urls.py`

```py
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url

from .views import FamilyCreateView, FamilyDetailView, FamilyListView

urlpatterns=patterns('',
                     url(r'^$',FamilyListView.as_view(),name='family-list'),
                     url(r'^create/$',FamilyCreateView.as_view(),name='family-create'),
                     url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',FamilyDetailView.as_view(),name='family-detail'),
                     url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/person/',include('person.urls',namespace='person')),
)
```

`addressbook/family/views.py`

```py
from django.views import generic
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from .models import Family

class FamilyListView(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name='family_list'
    model=Family


class FamilyDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    context_object_name='family'
    model=Family


class FamilyCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model=Family

    def get_success_url(self,**kwargs):
        return reverse('family-detail',kwargs={'pk':self.object.pk})
```

`addressbook/family/templates/family/family_detail.html`

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ family }}</h1>
<ul>
  {% for person in family.person_set.all %}
    <li>{{ person }}</li>
    {#<li><a href="{% url 'family:person:person-detail' person.pk %}">{{ person }}</a></li>#}
    {#<li><a href="{% url 'family:person:person-detail' person.family.pk person.pk %}">{{ person }}</a></li>#}
    {#<li><a href="{% url 'family:person:person-detail' pk=person.family.pk pk=person.pk %}">{{ person }}</a></li>#}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
<br><br><br>
<p><a href="{% url 'family:person:person-create' family.pk %}">Add family member</a></p>
<p><a href="{% url 'family:family-list' %}">Return to family list</a><p>
{% endblock content %}
```

`addressbook/family/templates/family/family_form.html`

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Add/Update Family</h1>
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<p><button type="submit">Save</button></p>
</form>
<br><br><br>
<p><a href="{% url 'family:family-list' %}">Return to family list</a></p>
{% endblock content %}
```

`addressbook/family/templates/family/family_list.html`

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for family in family_list %}
<ul>
  <li><a href="{% url 'family:family-detail' family.id %}">{{ family }}</a></li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
<br><br><br>
<a href="{% url 'family:family-create' %}">Create new family</a>
{% endblock content %}
```

`addressbook/person/models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from family.models import Family

class Person(models.Model):
    family=models.ForeignKey(Family)
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname
```

`addressbook/person/urls.py`

```py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import PersonCreateView, PersonDetailView

urlpatterns=patterns('',
                     url(r'^create/$', PersonCreateView.as_view(),name='person-create'),
                     url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',PersonDetailView.as_view(),name='person-detail'),
)
```

`addressbook/person/views.py`

```py
from django.views import generic
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Person
from family.models import Family

class PersonDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model=Person


class PersonCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model=Person

    def get_initial(self):
        family=get_object_or_404(Family,pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return {'family':family,}

    def get_success_url(self,**kwargs):
        return reverse('family:family-detail',args=[self.kwargs['pk']])
        #return reverse('person-detail',kwargs={'pk':self.object.pk})
```

`addressbook/person/templates/person/person_detail.html:`

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  {{ person }} {{ person.family }}
  <br><br>
<p><a href="{% url 'family:family-detail' person.family.pk %}">Return to family: {{ person.family }}</a></p>
{% endblock content %}
```

`addressbook/person/templates/person/person_form.html`

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Add/Update Person</h1>
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<p><button type="submit">Save</button></p>
</form>
<br><br><br>
{#<p><a href="{% url 'family:family-detail' family.pk %}">Return to family {{ family }}</a></p>#}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rethink your urls. Hopefully the following comments will help.

In your family urls you have

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/person/',include('person.urls',namespace='person')),
```

Then in your person urls you have

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',PersonDetailView.as_view(),name='person-detail'),
```

This suggests a url of the form `/family/<pk>/person/<pk>/`. That is invalid, as you have used the named argument pk twice in the same pattern.

If you rename one of your primary keys in the url pattern, for example:

```
url(r'^(?P<person_pk>\d+)/$',PersonDetailView.as_view(),name='person-detail'),
```

Then you can use the [`pk_url_kwarg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg) option in your PersonDetail view.

```
class PersonDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model=Person
    pk_url_kwarg = 'person_pk'
```

Note also that you have two arguments in the above url, but you only provide one argument when you try to reverse the url in the template. Where you have

```
<a href="{% url 'family:person:person-detail' person.pk %}">{{ person }}</a>
```

you need to provide the family pk and the person pk:

```
<a href="{% url 'family:person:person-detail' family.pk person.pk %}">{{ person }}</a>
```

Comment: Yes. `http://127.0.0.1:8080/family/1/person/1/` works when I have entered data. I just tried `url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/person/',include('person.urls',namespace='person')),` in `family/urls.py` and then `<li><a href="{% url 'family:person:person-detail' id=person.family.pk pk=person.pk %}">{{ person }}</a></li>` in `family_detail.html` but this gives `NoReverseMatch. Reverse for 'person-detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 1, 'id': 2}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['family/(?P<pk>\\d+)/person/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']`. So how to create multiple key variables and access them?

Comment: ah. I did not know `pk_url_kwarg` exists. That's probably exactly what I need. Thanks. Will try it and then mark your answer.

Comment: OK, glad that worked. I updated the answer to include instructions how to use `pk_url_kwarg`, which will hopefully help somebody in future.